# Unraveling nested unordered lists and displaying horizontally in IE/Chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nested-lists

I've been googling this for about a week, and I can't find a solution that works on all three browsers. I'm trying to find a way to output nested unordered lists horizontally using cross-platform css.

I've put together a mock up of what I'm trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/gNqJb/ If you click on the Tier1 and Tier 2 blocks (the menu starts expanded, so you'll need to do this first), you'll see the functionality I want. The idea is that if you click on a menu header it'll expand the sub-menus horizontally next to the header. The problem with this code is that the sub-menus are placed outside of a list item block (<.li>). Also, it doesn't work in IE at all. In this example, everything with a * in the name is a header block.

Since I'm working with Drupal, I'm stuck with its menus, which are output like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="first expanded"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first last leaf"><a href="#" class="active">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first expanded"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first last leaf"><a href="#" class="active">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first expanded"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first last leaf"><a href="#" class="active">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first expanded"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first last leaf"><a href="#" class="active">Test</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="first last leaf"><a href="#" class="active">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last leaf"><a href="#" class="active">Test Outside</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I apply the formatting to it, I get this: http://jsfiddle.net/C2eU4/

I would greatly appreciate any help in getting this layout fixed for use in IE/Chrome/FF with Drupal.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got a pure CSS solution that should at least get you going on how this should work.  The caveat is that the animation will only work in webkit browsers at the moment.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2eU4/3/)

Here are the relevant changes to your CSS:

```
li ul {
    width:0px;
    position: absolute;
    left:100%;
    top: -1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide;
   animation-name: slide;
   -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
   animation-duration: .5s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
   animation-direction: reverse;
}
li + li{
   -webkit-animation-name: push;
   animation-name: push;
   -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
   animation-duration: .5s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
   animation-direction: reverse;
}
li:hover ul {
   -webkit-animation-name: slide;
   animation-name: slide;
   -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
   animation-duration: .5s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
   animation-direction: normal;
   display:inline-block;
   width: 100px;
}
li:hover + li {
   -webkit-animation-name: push;
   animation-name: push;
   -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
   animation-duration: .5s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
   animation-direction: normal;
   margin-left: 100px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide{
   from {
     width: 0px;  
    }
   to {
     width: 100px;  
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes push{
   from {
     margin-left:0px;}
   to {
     margin-left:100px;}
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Alright, I went ahead and did it for jQuery too.  Slow day, I guess:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2eU4/2/)

Comment: Thanks for helping, Josh. I noticed that it doesn't do multiple levels of nested lists though. I'm going to see if I can use this to modify my current code.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult to get it working with children elements. The first thing I'd do is add an e.stopPropagation() call at the beginning of the click handler, or remove the menu class from subsequent nested ULs. I'm on my phone now, or I would test it out for ya.